# grocery store within / in compound

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct?

> What is the proper size of a grocery store **within** / **in** a compound that has 600 apartments.

Comment: Don't forget the articles for "grocery store" and "compound".

Comment: If you are talking about a smaller area inside a larger area, use *within*. If you are talking about location, use *in*. You example could be understood as either one, without more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both forms are possible.

- **Within**
  Mostly means inside or not further than an area or border.
- **In**
  Mostly indicates inclusion, location, or position within limits. It also
  indicates that someone or something belongs to or is included as part of
  something.

You could also try *inside* and *on the inside of* with your sentence. I prefer "in" or "inside" though:

> What is the proper size of a grocery store **in** *(inside, situated,
>   belongs to, is a part of)* a compound that has 600 apartments.

With *within* it sounds like it's situated somewhere on the inside of the compound; it is in there somewhere.

See definitions of **"within"** here: [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/within).

Comment: I disagree with your definition of "within." If something is "within a compound," it will always be inside it, not close to it. The Cambridge definition is vague, but consider [within (prep.) def. 1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/within) (Oxford Dictionaries); [within (prep.) def. 1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/within) (Merriam-Webster); and [def. 3](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/within) (Macmillan) which do not support "within" meaning "close to (a place)."

Comment: @LMS You are very right here, I've slightly misunderstood "within" **"The shop is withing 5 meters of the road"** is quite natural. So **within** means a range or a border too. A compound is a range all by itself already.